# see with clear eye or see clearly

Tags: word-choice

1. I can see it clearly.
2. I can see it with clear eyes.

I know that first point is correct. But I would like to know if the second one is correct or not. And also would like to know which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical. (1) is the normal expression if you have a sharp and uniterrupted vision of something. The occasions on which (2) would be required would be few, I'd have thought.

Comment: From the web: LITERAL USAGE: 'It's been a while since my boys looked at me with clear eyes' (They're usually tear-filled). // FIGURATIVE USAGE: '...if I want to understand something new I must look at it with clear eyes' (as opposed to through the eyes of prejudice).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the fact you added a qualifier to your figurative use reinforces my feeling that "clear eyes" is not readily understood.

Comment: @Kristina: I don't think it's so much a matter of "see with clear eyes" not being readily understood - it's just not *often* used in that sense, [by comparison with "see clearly"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see+with+clear+eyes%2Csee+clearly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csee%20with%20clear%20eyes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csee%20clearly%3B%2Cc0), against which it "flatlines". If you remove the dominant term in that chart, you'll see there quite enough instances of the "clear eyes" version to make a usage chart all on its own.

Answer (score 0):

One might guess that you translate expressions from your mother-tongue word for word into English. But that does not sound English. I think what you mean is "It can be seen clearly that + clause."

Answer (score 0):

We intend to, or we will see some subject with clear eyes. If we managed it, we can say we see it with clear eyes. But it is a bit immodest. It would be better if somebody else will evaluate our seeing the subject.

See clearly has even one more (close) meaning. We can see the complex subject clearly. And as a result of it, or not, we can see clearly some of its details. In other words, it is about looking into something or looking at something.

Comment: Seeing something with "clear eyes" just isn't commonly used.  Seeing something "clearly" is the common expression (at least in my English-speaking part of the world and in the literature I read).

Comment: "see with clear eyes" - 155k instances in Google. "see with clear eye" - 30k more. "sees with clear eyes" - 40K more. While "see clearly" - 1400k. Of course, "see with clear eyes" is a nice metaphor and not used by everybody everyday. I think, it comes from Tenisson "See with clear eye some hidden shame"

Comment: Not bad, and that actually surprises me but it's still far fewer than the 1,790,000 instances of "see clearly".

Comment: I have nothing against your point of view, but both are usable and correct, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, of course, both usable! :-)